# I have problem while converting logical model to Relational model in SQL data modeler

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I am trying to develop a database for my homework. I designed a Logical Model in SQL data modeler. I tried to convert it to Relational model but Relations were created as Tables. not like relations. I watched some videos on youtube and tried to do same tables. I got same problems again. Where is my mistake and how can I fix it? Thank you so much...

[Logical Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCs2r.jpg)

[Relational Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GVDT.jpg)

Comment: many-to-many relationship is implemented via cross table in relational databases

Comment: "but Relations were created as Tables" -- Tables are representations of relations in relational databases. So there's nothing wrong with the creation of tables.

Comment: Why do you have tables for "actors", "managers", "directors" and "producers" with duplicated fields (especially if 1 person can have multiple roles)? Why not have a single "people" table with the common (id, name, DoB and gender) fields and then you can have job related tables so that the data is in 3NF.

Comment: Logical Model relations **are** tables in the physical model. BTW Both are relational models.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are different terms used in data modelling, and several types of model provided by different tools and named differently, so exactly what a Relational Model is (I'd never heard of that one) will depend on the tool you are using. From the screenshot, it appears to be a physical model, which means tables, columns, foreign keys, indexes, storage details etc. If you wanted something different  then please describe what it is.

Traditionally there is

1. a logical model, also known as an entity model or entity relationship diagram (ERD), which is database agnostic and merely models business entities, their attributes, unique keys and relationships.
2. a physical model, defining a schema ready for implementing in a specific vendor's RDBMS. This has tables with columns, primary keys, check constraints, indexes etc.

In my experience, tools often blur the line between entities and tables.

The way I learned it, an entity is a conceptual item of interest to the business, like *"Doctor"* or *"Patient"*, because the purpose of the model is to show what a Doctor is and what a Patient is and how they are related, and that is why they are named in the singular. A database table, however, (in the physical model) will usually contain rows representing many Doctors and Patients and so the plural is appropriate. Opinions differ, though.